# Fibonacci numbers: proof4

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, fibonacci-numbers

I need to proove the following

$F_{n+k}=F_{k-1}F_{n}+F_{k}F_{n+1}$

Firstly, I wanted to use mathematic induction, but I do not know, to which letter ($n$ or $k$) should be $1$ added, or it does not matter?

I also tried to find out the solution on the Internet, but unsuccessfully.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to note:

1. The proposition you're assuming is $P(k)$ where $n, k \in \mathbb Z^+$
2. You need to set the "domain" as $k\geq2$ (i.e. your base case will be $P(2)$)
3. You need to use strong mathematical induction for this. You should consider *two* consecutive generic cases such as $P(m)$ and $P(m+1)$ and show that if they hold true, then $P(m+2)$ will also hold true for all $m \in \mathbb Z^+$

Does this help?

Here is the proof:

$$P(k): F_{n+k}=F_{k-1}F_{n}+F_{k}F_{n+1}$$

$$
\begin{align}
P(2): F_{n+2} 
&= F_{1}F_{n}+F_{1}F_{n+1}\\[1em]
&= 1\cdot F_{n}+1\cdot F_{n+1}\\[1em]
&= F_{n} + F_{n+1}\\[1em]
&= F_{n+2}\tag{{P(2) is true}}\\[1em]
\end{align}
$$

$$P(m): F_{n+m}=F_{m-1}F_{n}+F_{m}F_{n+1}\tag{1}$$

$$P(m+1): F_{n+m+1}=F_{m}F_{n}+F_{m+1}F_{n+1}\tag{2}$$

$$P(m+2): F_{n+m+2} = F_{m+1}F_{n}+F_{m+2}F_{n+1}\tag{{Show this}}$$

$$
\begin{align}
F_{n+m+2}
&= F_{n+m}+F_{n+m+1}\\[1em]
&= F_{m-1}F_{n}+F_{m}F_{n+1}+F_{m}F_{n}+F_{m+1}F_{n+1}\tag{using (1) and (2)}\\[1em]
&= F_{n}(F_{m-1}+F_{m})+F_{n+1}(F_{m}+F_{m+1})\\[1em]
&= F_{m+1}F_{n}+F_{m+2}F_{n+1}\\[1em]
\end{align}
$$

$\implies P(m+2)$ holds true.

$\implies P(k)$ holds true.

Comment: ye, you helped me, but now I've few more questions..

I don't really understand why k≥2. Is it connected to generic cases (like I have two cases, so for all other cases k must be≥2?)? Because otherwise, I can also use k=1 and the equation has solution.
 
moreover, I've never see strong math. induction so far, so if I understand it good I have

$F_{n+k}=F{k−1}F_n+F_kF_{n+1}$
$F_{n+1+k}=F_{k−1}F_{n+1}+F_kF_{n+2}$
$F_{n+2+k}=F_{k−1}F_{n+2}+F_kF_{n+3}$ 
from that 
$F{k−1}F_n+F_kF_{n+1}+F_{k−1}F_{n+1}+F_kF_{n+2}=F_{k−1}F_{n+2}+F_kF_{n+3}$
and I am hopeless with this...

Comment: @martina I'd suggest using $k\geq2$ because in some contexts $F_0$ doesn't have a proper definition as $0$. You can definitely do it with $k\geq1$ though if you accept the definition that $F_0=0$. As for strong induction, I'd suggest you to look at [this](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~stephens/203/PDF/4-4.pdf) for an idea of how to use it. For fibonacci numbers you need to, because you have to consider the previous *two* cases, not one, because by definition $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$.

Comment: @martina I added the whole proof. That should clear your doubts.

Comment: I have it, that is why I didn´t answered. Thank you very much.